# REGEXP_REPLACE on a CLOB in Oracle 11g fails with - No more data to read from socket

Tags: regex, oracle

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

1. `create a table temp_reg_exp_issue with one VARCHAR2(4000) column [column name = V_DESCRIPTION].`
2. Insert a row with a string of length 2001 characters.
3. Perform the following select - 
        `select REGEXP_REPLACE ( XMLCAST(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,V_DESCRIPTION, '##')
         ) AS CLOB), '([^##]+)(##\1)+', '\1' ) AS ENTITY from temp_reg_exp_issue;`
4. Fails with - No more data to read from socket.
5. It works fine with 2000 length string

I ran the query in apex.oracle.com which has the following oracle version.
**Oracle Database 18c EE Extreme Perf Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 18.7.0.0.0**

It fails with the same error here too.

Is this some bug in oracle? Help needed please. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you casting a varchar column into a clob? just run the regex on the original column.

Comment: What do you expect `[^##]` to do?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, Thanks for your response. i am using a clob because the net length, if there are more rows, will turn out to be more than 4000 characters. And a varchar2 cannot hold it.

Comment: @CAustin - Thanks for your response. This is a regular expression syntax. It will look for all non '##' characters

Comment: `[^##]` = `[^##]`, there is no regex construct to match any text but two or more character substring (it is available in Lucene regex engine only). You probably might use `'(.*?)(##\1)+'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That one too gives the same error.

Comment: @Vinay `[^##]` is the same as `[^#]` in regex. Character sets only select one of the characters they contain, not sequential strings. Maybe you're looking for negative lookbehind or something.

Comment: @CAustin, I tried substituting [^##] with [^#] where ever applicable in the whole query. I still get the same error. The point i am not able to understand is if the query works for 2000 characters, why is not working for string length > 2000. Is there some limitation that oracle has imposed or is it some bug in oracle. –